# NullPointerException when changing from scene with ListView

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am getting a `NullPointerException` when changing from a scene with a `ListView`.

I have a main "home" page, which loads `Main.fxm`l, with a `ListView`, that when populated, breaks the app and causes it to not be able to change scenes. It works fine if the `ListView` is not populated.

Main controller that holds methods used by controllers for other scenes:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML ListView<String> list;
    @FXML Button toLoginScreen;
    //other FXML elements

    public void changeView(String page, ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(page));
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        Stage stage = (Stage)((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void loginButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        changeView("Login.fxml", event);
    }

        //other methods

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        list.getItems().add("an item");
    }
```

The Main.fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
//imports
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
    <top>
        <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <ToolBar>
                    <items>
                        <Button fx:id="toLoginPage" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginButtonAction" text="Login" />
                    </items>
                </ToolBar>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </top>
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <items>
                <AnchorPane>
                    <children>
                        <AccordionprefHeight="356.0" prefWidth="246.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                            <panes>
                                <TitledPane animated="false" text="List 1">
                                    <content>
                                        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                            <children>
                                                <ListView fx:id="list" prefHeight="280.0"   prefWidth="244.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
                                            </children>
                                        </AnchorPane>
                                    </content>
                                </TitledPane>
                            </panes>
                        </Accordion>
                    </children>
                </AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane />
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Full error trace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 48 more

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:/path/Project/bin/application/Login.fxml
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Controller.changeView(Controller.java:42)
at application.loginController.loginButtonAction(loginController.java:33)
... 58 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:91)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
... 67 more
```

If I try to go from the main scene to the Login scene I get a NullPointerException at the

```
list.getItems().add("an item");
```

in the `Controller`'s `initialize` method.

Comment: `Main.fxml` may contain a `<ListView>` element with `fx:id="list"`, but this doesn't seem to be the case for `Login.fxml`

Comment: @fabian Yes, the login page doesn't have this list. It is supposed to only live in the main scene.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of having the `initialize` method in the main `Controller`, having it instead on the specific controller for the scene works.

Comment: I recommend taking a few more JavaFX tutorials to really get the basics down.